# What is the idiomatic Haskell-way to act on predicates in IO?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, predicate, io-monad

For some file operation, I need to check if the file exists, if it has been modified, and only then perform some operation on it. My newbie Haskell code looks as follows (simplified):

```
someFileOp ::FileContents -> FilePath -> IO (FileOpResult)
someFileOp contents absFilePath = do
    fileExists <- DIR.doesFileExist absFilePath
    if fileExists
        then do
            isMod <- isModified contents absFilePath
            if isMod
                then return FileModified
            else return $ doSomethingWithFile
        else return FileNotFound
```

It does work. However, the nested if-expressions look *wrong* to me - not FP-like. What would be an idiomatic way to check several Boolean conditions in IO and then take some action depending on their result?

Comment: Not really a Haskell-specific thing, but: I wouldn't bother with `doesFileExist`. Instead catch the exception that `isModified` throws when it doesn't exist. Otherwise you have a race condition.

Comment: This is decent functionnal programming, and certainly easy to understand, which is in my opinion a quality. If you want to "chain" this you can look for an infix operator that evaluates the RHS when LHS IO returns True. Also, the Either monad may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted looks fine to me. Another possibility would be to act in a short-circuiting monad like `ExceptT Err IO`.

```
data Err = FileNotFound | FileModified

getFileContents :: FilePath -> ExceptT Err IO FileContents
getFileContents fp = do
    exists <- doesFileExist fp
    if exists then {- ... -} else throwError FileNotFound

someFileOp :: FileContents -> FilePath -> ExceptT Err IO FileOpResult
someFileOp fc fp = do
    fc' <- getFileContents fp
    when (fc /= fc') (throwError FileModified)
    doSomethingWithFile
```

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring Daniel's good point on races and why checking for files is often just not done, the more Haskell solution is usually a monad transformer.  This is a typical case where an ExceptT transformer makes sense.  I've also included a (mis)use of ContT in case you're curious and want to explore:

```
import System.Directory as DIR
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

isModified :: a -> b -> IO Bool
isModified _ _ = pure False

type FileOpResult = Either String String

someFileOp_cont :: String -> FilePath -> IO FileOpResult
someFileOp_cont contents absFilePath = evalContT $ callCC $ \exit -> do
    fileExists <- liftIO $ DIR.doesFileExist absFilePath
    unless fileExists (exit (Left "FileNotFound"))
    isMod <- liftIO $ isModified contents absFilePath
    when isMod (exit (Left "FileModified"))
    return (Right "doSomethingWithFile")

someFileOp_except :: String -> FilePath -> IO FileOpResult
someFileOp_except contents absFilePath = runExceptT $ do
    fileExists <- liftIO $ DIR.doesFileExist absFilePath
    unless fileExists (throwE "FileNotFound")
    isMod <- liftIO $ isModified contents absFilePath
    when isMod (throwE "FileModified")
    return "doSomethingWithFile"
```

Comment: Is this really anymore of a misuse of `ContT` than any other use? :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `whenM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m()` or `ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a`, available for example in [`extra`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.2/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:whenM):

```hs
-- | Like 'when', but where the test can be monadic.
whenM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m () -> m ()
whenM mb mt = mb >>= \b ->
  if b
    then mt
    else return ()

-- | Like @if@, but where the test can be monadic.
ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
ifM mb mt me = mb >>= \b ->
  if b
    then mt
    else me
```